# url id masking with hashids : Connection [App\User] not configured

Tags: php, laravel, url

I was following a tutorial by ben sampo on url masking and am getting the error Connection [App\User] not configured.

#### app.php in config

```
        'Hashids' => Vinkla\Hashids\Facades\Hashids::class,
```

#### hashids.php

```
 'connections' => [

    'main' => [
        'salt' => 'your-salt-string',
        'length' => 'your-length-integer',
    ],

    'alternative' => [
        'salt' => 'your-salt-string',
        'length' => 'your-length-integer',
    ],
    \App\User::class => [
        'salt' => \App\User::class.'7623e9b0009feff8e024a689d6ef59ce',
        'length' => 5,
    ],

],
```

#### web.php

```
Route::get('/home/{user}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

#### trait  hashidable.php

```
 <?php
namespace App\Http\Traits;
trait Hashidable
{
    public function getRouteKey()
    {
        return \Hashids::connection(get_called_class())->encode($this->getKey());
    }
}
```

#### User.php

```
 use Hashidable;
```

#### RouteServiceProvider.php

```
 public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    
    Route::bind('user', function ($value, $route) {
        return $this->getModel(\App\User::class, $value);
    });
}
    // added by rap
    private function getModel($model, $routeKey)
{
    $id = \Hashids::connection($model)->decode($routeKey)[0] ?? null;
    $modelInstance = resolve($model);

    return  $modelInstance->findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help your question, or do you still have problems?

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding here, `\Hashids::connection($model)` should not be the model. It should be the connection you have defined in your config.

To make hashids work, you need to create your config. You can create your config file like so `php artisan vendor:publish`. From there it should look something similar to this.

```
return [
    'default' => 'our_connection',

    'connections' => [
        'our_connection' => [
            'salt'   => 'your-salt',
            'length' => 6,
            'alphabet' => 'RANDOM CHARACTERS',
        ],
   ],
];
```

Now you can utilise the default connection, or specify the connection you want to use.

```
\Hashids::connection('our_connection')
```

Everything here is fairly well described in the [documentation](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, these are my codes.

**I didn't put in app.php**

```
'Hashids' => Vinkla \ Hashids \ Facades \ Hashids :: class,
```

**my file hashids.php**

```
'connections' => [

    \App\Models\User::class => [
        'salt' => \App\Models\User::class.'fe4898dfe2fb8422f6dc8f79146d214d',
        'length' => 10,
    ],
    \App\Models\Course::class => [
        'salt' => 
  \App\Models\Course::class.'6dc29bf420a127578beaacab45f41351',
        'length' => 8,
    ],
    \App\Models\Unit::class => [
        'salt' => \App\Models\Unit::class.'c91a52c63222c1080a104b21f3331a60',
        'length' => 12,
    ],

],
```

my trait file is the same as yours and my file RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('user', function ($value, $route) {
        return $this->getModel(User::class, $value);
    });

    Route::bind('unit', function ($value, $route) {
        return $this->getModel(Unit::class, $value);
    });

    Route::bind('course', function ($value, $route) {
        return $this->getModel(Course::class, $value);
    });
}

protected function getModel($model, $routeKey) {
    $id = \Hashids::connection($model)->decode($routeKey)[0] ?? null;
    $modelInstance = resolve($model);
    return $modelInstance->findOrFail($id);
}
```

the solution was just to run this command **php artisan config:clear** I had the same problem and this solved everything

[solved hashids not configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWO0p.png)